# How the Kv rating relates to power generation with BLDC motors

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, generator

I am confused about how the Kv rating of a bldc motor affects the 3 phase ac it generates because, the Kv rating is based on the dc voltages that are applied to the motor by its esc. So for example, if i had a 1000 Kv motor and spun it at 1000 rpm would the motor generate 1 volt rms or something else and what would the peak voltage be?

Comment: "KV" is meaningless. "kV" is kilovolts and "Kv" is probably what you are trying to express.

Comment: Don't be so harsh, Andy. Some people do capitalize the 'V'. as long as they don't say "kV," it is all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a BLDC, Kv is based on half of the peak-to-peak voltage. In other words, it is based on the amplitude of the sine-wave voltage. The units of Kv are rpm/Volt.

So to measure it, spin the motor at a known RPM, and measure the amplitude of the phase-to-phase voltage. So let's say you measure the voltage and it is 10V peak-to-peak, or 5V in amplitude. Let's say the motor is spinning at 1000 RPM. Then the Kv is 1000 RPM / 5V = 200.

This measurement is done when the current in the windings is zero. If you are using the motor as a generator, then the output voltage will be lower than the Kv predicts due to resistive losses in the copper windings. If you are driving the motor, the phase-to-phase voltage will be higher than the Kv predicts also due to resistive losses in the motor windings.

The wikipedia page on motor constants can be used as a reference, however I have experience measuring motor Kv to compare with manufacturer specifications.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants#Motor_velocity_constant,_back_EMF_constant

In your example, you say you are spinning at 1000rpm and the Kv is 1000rpm/V. So you take 1000 rpm and divide by 1000 rpm/V and the result is 1V.

Note: that is not the RMS voltage. It is the peak voltage of the sine wave, which is also half of the peak-to-peak voltage.

Comment: Kudos for the correction to term for \$K_v\$  But  is it really "Konstant of voltage " as in DE language origin or just K as in the EE std. control system variable letter?  even though it is commonly published as KV

Comment: If a BLDC motor is ideal and lossless and has \$K_v=1000 RPM/5V=200\$ not 20 , so if the motor spins at 1000 RPM with 5V peak sinusoid 3 phase drive, WILL IT RUN FASTER with Full DC 3 phase drive? or the same RPM? So is it average BEMF, Peak EMF or RMS EMF? If peak, any references?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I corrected my math error. Thank you! Kv is a property of the motor. It tells you how to estimate the magnitude of the back EMF. That is it. However, I believe motors will generally spin a bit faster using 6-step commutation vs sine wave drive, assuming the DC-link voltage is the same in both cases. However this can be compensated to some extent using field weakening techniques. So a motor can spin faster than Kv predicts by deliberately applying the drive voltage earlier than the EMF.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I don't know what the 'K' really stands for. I think of it as the motor voltage constant, and I know that 'K' is often used as a constant in science notation.

Comment: Yes I think so. But the real question is this constant of RPM/V based on sine (pk,rms or average back EMF or DC as a motor)  Those who use DC as a motor get tend to get the wrong result from the thesis topics I read.

Comment: It is based on peak voltage for sure. I added a reference to the wikipedia article on it. Wikipedia is explicit on that point. Also, I have had enough experience measuring Kv on motors that I know what I am talking about from first hand experience. Of course, your DC supply will have to be a bit higher than speed/Kv, because you need to deliver current to the motor (to produce torque). It is not enough for your driver circuit to supply a voltage equal to the back EMF. You have to exceed it.

Comment: As noted earlier, it IS possible to drive a BLDC faster than Kv * VDC. But you have to be able to supply the phase voltages with leading phase, so you need a position encoder, or you need to track rotor position in real time somehow.

Comment: The assumption is always that commutation is ideal such as with encoder or Hall sense detectors and drivers either sine or square.  But the question remains, is it Vpk of a sine output or Vrms or Vavg or Vdc of 3 phase drive

Comment: No. Kv is NOTHING TO DO with the driving circuit. It is the peak voltage of the back EMF. It is best observed when the phases are open-circuit. Trying to measure Kv while driving the motor is just making the job more difficult, though of course it can be done if you know the current and compensate for loss in the windings.

Comment: so the Kv would be accurate in motor mode using Vp sine such as a VFD with no load ( or friction ) so we that be the same Kv in a motor using DC commutated instead of Vp sinusoid. ( if lossless)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80529/discussion-between-mkeith-and-tony-ee-rocketscientist).